Checking for Indices Manually
How do I check indices of a given integer number manually?
For example,
I have a number. I want to check the indices and determine whether they are even or not. Should I turn it into a an array check for indices? I'm a bit lost.
If I turn it to an array, and each element of the array is one of the digits of the number, then that would work. But I don't know how to do that? Is such thing possible?
So far I've writen;
    char x = e + '0';
    int count;
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        index = i;
        if (index % 2 == 1){
        index /= 3;
        }
    

After checking for indices, I will multiply digits with odd indices by 3, that's what I tried to do in the code with "*3" but I'm finding it hard to conceptualize the checking for digits part.

It's perverse to convert a string input to an integer and then back to an array. Input the number as a string: that's an array. Then each digit value is array[i] - '0' .

Explain the division by 3, that doesn't make any sense. Also indent your code properly.

It's also unclear whether the index should be even, or the digit value.

@Jabberwocky My bad. I think I asked the question wrong. But my question still holds. I have a number with 13 digits. If index of the number is odd, I should multiply the number with 3, but I cannot find a way to investigate digits or indices manually. Should I delete this question and ask another one, I'm new to this forum so I don't know how it works yet.

So if you are trying to implement Luhn's algorithm, a card number is not an integer. It's a digit string. And I guess the *3 is for odd index not odd digit.

@AStudent XY Problem alert: please tell us what you're actually trying to achieve.

Code shows "divide by 3", but comment states "multiply by 3"... Time for a break. Probably best to delete your question, go drink a cup of coffee and work out what it is you are trying to do, then come back and edit your question (yes you CAN do that) and "undelete" it again... Otherwise EVERYONE wastes their time...

@WeatherVane I think they're similar but no. I'm trying to implement an ean number and it's given to me as an integer. int ean13(uint64_t ean) {} this is the format and I'm supposed to implement in the brackets.

Please make the question clearer: 3189 isn't an EAN number.

@Fe2O3 You're right... I edited it.

Please also use the uint64_t that you mention in comment. A 32-bit int cannot hold an EAN number.

char x = ean + '0'; makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to achieve with this line?

@AStudent are you trying to achieve this: To compute the check digit of an EAN number follow the simple rules: sum all the digits in even positions and multiply by 3;
Add all the the digits in odd positions (except for the last one which is check digit) to the number you’ve got; Divide that number by 10 and take the remainder;
If the remainder is not 0, subtract it from 10.

@Jabberwocky I thought I would convert the given number to a string first.

@AStudent no, it doesn't do that. You need to use for example sprintf as suggested in one of the answers below.

The code should never have been an integer in the first place. The ISBN (similar to EAN-13) checksum can be 'X'.

@Jabberwocky No. I need to add all digits together, digits at odd indices are multiplied by 3, and if the end sum is a multiple of 10 then my number is 'valid'.

@WeatherVane If student is struggling with all numeric EAN-13, why muddy the water with ISBN... Someone struggling with "miles per gallon to litres per kilometre" doesn't need to be concerned about "EV charging times and range"...

Here's how you can extract digits from a number:
    int number = 3189;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        int digit = number % 10; // Extract the last digit
        if (digit % 2 == 0) // check if digit is even
           even++;
        else
           odd++;
        number = number / 10; // Remove the last digit
    }

I am assuming that given number is in integer and you are only concerned about finding number of even and odd digits.
Quick dry run:
3189

Iteration1: 
digit = 9
even = 0, odd = 1
number = 318

Iteration2: 
digit = 8
even = 1, odd = 1
number = 31

Iteration3: 
digit = 1
even = 1, odd = 2
number = 3

Iteration4: 
digit = 3
even = 1, odd = 3
number = 0


What if the "number" has one or more leading zeros?

Suggest "Least Significant Digit" instead of "last digit"... It pays to be precise...

Integer data type doesn't store leading zeros. That's why I have mentioned in the answer that I am assuming that given number is integer.

Exactly: if the input contains leading zeros, they will be lost. A 'given number' is one that has been input from somewhere. And a 'number' isn't always an integer, but may be a digit string.

This will give the wrong answer for 0.

We can add following for zero. if (number == 0)   even = 1;

Simpler to convert to a string with sprint()/snprint() (even better if input is taken in the form of a string):
char str[/* Some max limit that would be enough */];
sprintf(str, "%d", /* Some integer literal or variable */); /* Use the proper format specifier if it is not an `int` */

// Now you can iterate through the characters and do your processing.

Then each digit value is array[i] - '0'. - @Weather Vane
Though, have you checked whether an int can hold 13 digits? I'd suggest using uint64_t/uintmax_t or some other type.
